# Using a dict as a key when not all values exist

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a situation where some city names need to be renamed, so I am using a dict where the keys are the old city names and the values are the new ones. However, only some cities need to be renamed so not all possible cities are in the dict.

The only way I know how to do it is to except a KeyError when the city doesn't need to be renamed, which works, but I'm not sure if this is bad practice, or if there are any downfalls to this. Is there something I am missing?

```
# Set Venue
venue_name = unidecode(cell[2].get_text())
try:
    # Correct venue names i.e. Cairns, QLD = Cairns
    venue_name = VENUE_NAMES_DICT[venue_name]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: Use dict.get(key, default_value)

Comment: @jarmod if you add an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jarmod suggests, you can use the `.get()` method of the standard Dictionary to provide a default value in case the key is missing. What isn't described is that this approach enables you to turn your problem into a one-liner by passing the `venue_name` value to `.get()` as the default value.

```
# Set Venue
venue_name = unidecode(cell[2].get_text())
# Correct venue names i.e. Cairns, QLD = Cairns
venue_name = VENUE_NAMES_DICT.get(venue_name, venue_name)
```

If `venue_name` is present as a key in the dictionary, `.get()` will return the desired new value. If it isn't present, `.get()` will return the original value of `venue_name` unchanged. This eliminates the need for any conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list) #this will return a empty list everytime a new key is used or if key exists it will appendt the value to the list
d[venue_name]=a
```

Example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> city_list = [('TX','Austin'), ('TX','Houston'), ('NY','Albany'), ('NY', 'Syracuse'), ('NY', 'Buffalo'), ('NY', 'Rochester'), ('TX', 'Dallas'), ('CA','Sacramento'), ('CA', 'Palo Alto'), ('GA', 'Atlanta')]
>>>
>>> cities_by_state = defaultdict(list)
>>> for state, city in city_list:
...     cities_by_state[state].append(city)
...
for state, cities in cities_by_state.iteritems():
...     print state, ', '.join(cities)
...
NY Albany, Syracuse, Buffalo, Rochester
CA Sacramento, Palo Alto
GA Atlanta
TX Austin, Houston, Dallas
```

Comment: i would rather just use "in" like @kbball suggested

Comment: @majorcoder Yeah ,I just gave you an intro to defaultdict which might be useful in cases where you don't know the occurrence of keys.@kkball answer is better for this question.

Comment: may I know the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "in", like this:

```
data = ['Chicago', 'NYC', 'Boston', 'SD']

dictionary = {'NYC': 'New York', 'SD': 'San Diego'}

new_list = []

for x in data:
    if x in dictionary:
        new_list.append(dictionary[x])
    else:
        new_list.append(x)

print(new_list)

#output

['Chicago', 'New York', 'Boston', 'San Diego']
```

Using List comprehension

```
data = ['Chicago', 'NYC', 'Boston', 'SD']
dictionary = {'NYC': 'New York', 'SD': 'San Diego'}
new_list=[dictionary[x] if x in dictionary else x for x in data]
print(new_list)


['Chicago', 'New York', 'Boston', 'San Diego']
```

Comment: I love when people down vote and don't comment

Comment: It was one of the other answerers.

Comment: @COLDSPEED it's one of my pet peeves on this site. I'm interested in feedback on any of my answers but have no idea what to do with a down vote and no comment

Comment: This would surprise you, but most users aren't as receptive to downvotes or feedback as  you would think. Providing feedback links you to downvotes and would just encourage revenge voting.

Comment: Apparently... It's odd that people are more interested in rep than exchanging ideas and learning, but I digress...

Comment: They've toyed with the idea of requiring comments with every down-vote, and this gets suggested on meta at least 5 times a week (or more), but it always gets turned down, mainly due to experience of most of us of getting bitten for posting the comments. As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ aptly states, most posters will only argue with the down-voter rather than be receptive to any sort of criticism to their question or answer.

Comment: I will mention though that your answer could use more explanation clarifying why you recommend your code, making it much more helpful to future visitors and not just the OP, and *this* could be a valid reason to down-vote it, and is in fact one of the most frequent reasons that I've down-voted answers before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict.get(key, default_value) and supply a default value.

Answer (score -1):

In general, throwing exceptions for non-exceptional situations is poor design. You want a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

renames = defaultdict(lambda: None)
# Add the elements to renames here ...
```

Now, `renames` is a dictionary, except that if the key doesn't exist, it returns `None` rather than throwing, so you can just check if the value `is None` to see if it needs to be renamed.

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvote, exactly, on this one.